# How to check for the existence of directive in Apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I am trying to edit a configuration file so that it will work simultaneously on Apache 2.2 and Apache 2.4.

The file was originally written for Apache 2.2 and includes the following config:

```
RewriteLogLevel 3
RewriteLog /var/log/httpd/apache_rewrite_log
```

However, `RewriteLogLevel` is no longer supported in Apache 2.4.  Instead, in that situation, I need to use:

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
```

Essentially what I'd like to do is:

```
<IfDirective LogLevel>
  LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
</IfDirective>
<IfDirective RewriteLog>
  RewriteLogLevel 3
  RewriteLog /var/log/httpd/apache_rewrite_log
</IfDirective>
```

However, `IfDirective` does not seem to be a thing in Apache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a method to check the existence of a specific directive. (You can check for the presence of whole modules using `<IfModule>`, but `RewriteLog`/`RewriteLogLevel` is part of mod_rewrite in Apache 2.2 and `LogLevel` is part of the *core* in Apache 2.4, so that doesn't help us unfortunately.)

However, we can check the Apache version using `<IfVersion>` and process directives accordingly.

For example, [`LogLevel`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#loglevel) is available from version 2.3.6 and later:

```
<IfVersion >= 2.3.6>
  LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion !>= 2.3.6>
  RewriteLogLevel 3
  RewriteLog /var/log/httpd/apache_rewrite_log
</IfVersion>
```

The `!` prefix on the second directive simply reverses the meaning. This could instead be written as `<IfVersion < 2.3.6>`.

Comment: Is `IfVersion` guaranteed to be available by default in all or most Apache 2.2 configurations?

Comment: `IfVersion` is part of mod_version from Apache 2.0 onwards. However, it is an _Extension_, so it might not be enabled by default, on any version of Apache (in the same way mod_rewrite might not be enabled). However, you must already be in control of the server anyway - so this should not be an issue.